# jvmargs=-xmx2048m dex in process for cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin

cordova build tells me the following

> To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It
>   currently has approximately 910 MB. For faster builds, increase the
>   maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB. To do
>   this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project
>   gradle.properties. For more information see
>   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

how can I set the jvmargs to -xmx2084M in cordova? Is it possible through config.xml or do I have to use hooks?

Cheers & Thanks

Qiong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qiong
You nee to put a file named `build-extras.gradle`in your `platforms/android` folder. Cordova will read the file automatically and will load the configuration for you.
You can do this manually or by a hook. The problem of the first option is that if you erase your platform folder, the will be erased as well.

The content of the file specifies the maximum heap size:

```
android {
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048m"
  }
}
```

If you want to go with the hook option, the content of the should be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var rootdir = process.argv[2];
if(fs.existsSync(rootdir + '/platforms/android')){
  console.log('Add build-extras.gradle');
  fs.createReadStream(rootdir + '/build-extras.gradle').pipe(fs.createWriteStream(rootdir + '/platforms/android/build-extras.gradle'));
}
```

And you need to put the file on `hooks/after_prepare/` folder. This will run your hook automatically.

Comment: thanks! this looks right, there is an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10096 which is supposed to be resolved, but for me its not working, has that change already been released?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this environment variable before starting the gradle daemon

```
export GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx2g
```

*edit*

Wait.. why can you not just do what the message says?

> *set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties*