# Unable run simple google map app

Tags: android, google-maps

MapsAcitivity.java

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {   

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
   @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

ERROR is this:

To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 5 mins 5.517 secs
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jvmargs=-xmx2048m dex in process for cordova](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853808/jvmargs-xmx2048m-dex-in-process-for-cordova)

Comment: If not using Cordova, [follow my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38853892/1790644).